# Version question of MiKTex along with TeXworks on Windows 10

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker

Recently I downloaded MiKTeX on my Hewlett Packard laptop having Windows 10 operating system. But I don't know its version.

1. How I can find it out?

   a) Is it necessary to install portable edition and command-line installer on my laptop?
2. Is it necessary to download and install Texmaker on my laptop for preparing documents in Chemistry?
3. What is the meaning of **pdfLaTeX  + MakeIndex + BibTeX?**

If any member knows the correct answers to these questions may reply.

Comment: Hi and welcome. The easiest way is to compile a .tex file and look at the first line of the `.log` file.

Comment: Regarding 2: `TeXMaker`is one of many LaTeX editors. For an overview over availavle editors you can take a look here: [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/134144). You can chose whichever editor you like best (or even decide to not use one at all and compile your documents via command line). Which editor to chose is, in first approximation, unrelated to the contents you want to write about.

Comment: Regarding 3: `pdfLaTeX` is the progam that you use to compile your .tex file with. The result is a .pdf file. `MakeIndex` is a program that helps you sort entries into an index/glossary. `BibTex` is a reference management software that helps creating formatted lists of references. `pdfLaTeX +MakeIndex + BibTeX` now means: use `pdfLaTeX`, then use `MakeIndex`, then use `BibTex`. Moste LaTex editors can do that (semi)automatically for you.

Comment: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/134144) as well as https://www.learnlatex.org/ might be worth having a look at.

Comment: `Makeindex` is an index compiler, if you want to add an index to your document. Bibtex is a bibliography compiler, if you want  to add a bibliography.